# loop data vs mysql WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, performance

What would work faster:

- Running a query with: 
  JOIN 2 tables(18000 rows , 15500 rows) and filter the data with multiple WHERE (9-12 WHERE's), so that I get only 15 rows result. 
  I need to run this query 4 times with different WHERE filters, and each time add the result items to a different array (4 arrays).

OR

- Run a query once: 
  JOIN 2 tables(18000 rows , 15500 rows) get all the data back, and loop through the results, In the loop I will have 4 if statements (which will basically replace the WHERE filters) and add the matching items to the arrays.

?

Comment: I think it will be better if you make the statements directly to mysql engine than to return so many rows to filter yourself.

Comment: It depends on your table structure, what type of processing you do. Try both options and see which one is faster.

Comment: if the where clauses use the same fields but different values, you should use parameterised queries as this will allow the SQL engine to cache the query, giving the best performance.

Comment: Also depends on the processing power and ram available to the machine but typically its quicker to do any sorting on the db server rather than in script.  This is because in high load environments the DB server is usually a beefy ass machine and the web server is the Pentium 2 sat in a corner with the 4 year old half drank cup of coffee on it... or is that just my web servers oO

Comment: Considering the performance, memory usage etc, it is not advisable to return all the results back and loop through them if there number is results is high.  But you can do some filtering in the business logic (Java language in my case) for some of the operations that are so costly in mysql.  For example, instead of using LIKE '%text%' on an unindexed field in mysql, this filtering can be done in java logic after getting the results back.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing *both* with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when <where1> then 1 else 0 end) as Where1,
       (case when <where2> then 1 else 0 end) as Where2,
. . .
```

Then you can bring back a smallish set of rows, and determine where they go in the application.

Your question is hard to answer because it depends on the time taken to process the query, to return results, and to go through the result set in the application.  In general, I would think that returning tens of thousands of rows would be a bad thing (performance-wise), compared to only returning a handful of rows.  However, in some environments, it might be the better approach.

If all your `where` clauses are returning disjoint sets of rows, then you can put them in a single derived column:

```
select (case when <where1> then 'where1'
             when <where2> then 'where2'
             . . .
        end) as which
```